# Datatable not applied

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datatables

I have inserted the `.js` and `.css` files in below order. But the `.DataTable()` function does not change my table with `id="testTable"`

```
<spring:url value="/resources/jquery-1.12.4.min.js" var="minJS" />
<script src="${minJS}"></script>
<spring:url value="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" var="bootJS1" />
<script src="${bootJS1}"></script>
<spring:url value="http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js" var="datatable" />
<script src="${datatable}"></script>
<spring:url value="http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" var="datacss" />
<link href="${datacss}" rel="stylesheet" />
<spring:url value="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" var="BOOT" />
<link href="${BOOT}" rel="stylesheet" />
<spring:url value="/resources/BIS.js" var="aJS" />
<script src="${aJS}"></script>
<spring:url value="/resources/a.css" var="acSS" />
<link href="${acSS}" rel="stylesheet" />


<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#testTable').DataTable();
  });
</script>
```

Please suggest what I might be doing wrong.

Comment: is `#testTable` exists before you calling  `$('#testTable').DataTable();` ? or generated dynamically ?

Comment: #testTable is exist.

Comment: so please see what browser console says.

Comment: @MamdouhFreelancer thanks for your quick response again. I dint find anyhing on console. But ran same project multiple times. Finally the changes applied.

Comment: `"  Finally the changes applied. "` >>> Solved!